# Best way to compare two authentication tokens

Tags: symfony

Consider the following example: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html#the-listener

I want to see if the new authenticated token is the same as for the currently logged in user. See below.

```
try {
    $currentToken = $this->securityContext->getToken(); 
    $authToken = $this->authenticationManager->authenticate($token);

    // What is the best way to compare these two? Both implement TokenInterface.
    if ([compare tokens]) {
        // already logged in
        return;
    }

    $this->tokenStorage->setToken($authToken);

    return;
} catch (AuthenticationException $failed) {
}
```

I considered comparing `UserInterface->getUsername()`:

```
if ($currentToken->getUser()->getUsername() === $authToken->getUser()->getUsername()) {
```

But wonder if there is a better solution...

Answer (score 0):

I assume both user object aren't the same reference. Because if they are you could compare them using `===` to check if they are the same.

Given that username is unique than this is one way to check if it is the same user. 
But in some systems the username doesn't have to be unique. So comparing the id's might be better since they should alway be unique.

Comment: No, they are not the same reference. Also, UserInterface doesn't have an id property.

Comment: Even though the interface doesn't have it, as long as your User class has a getId() function you can use that comparison - `if ($currentToken->getUser()->getId() === $authToken->getUser()->getId()) {`

Comment: Ah ofcourse, forgot they don´t het getId(). If username isn't unique, you could use the email field.

@JasonRoman The interface is there as a contract which garanties the methods will be available. Just using getId() because your entity has one breaks this contract.

Answer (score 0):

What about leveraging the code they show in the authenticate() function?

`$currentUser = $this->userProvider->loadUserByUsername($currentToken->getUsername());`

then

`$tokenUser = $this->userProvider->loadUserByUsername($authToken->getUsername());`

then

`if ($currentUser == $tokenUser) {`